# Creating pdf in android using itext

Tags: java, android, itext

I have a problem in creating a pdf using itext in android eclipse

I am not able to create a pdf if the bootstrap entries are given, in my case Android 5.0.1. If i remove bootstrap entries i am able to create the pdf but not able to start the activity as android 5.0.1 contains the android jar. Can you you please tell me how i can fix this issue? 
Also if i make it a non activity class i want to be able to create an object of the Non activity class in another activity class so that i can call a method from the activity class . Please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Download iText API from here http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg and add this to your project.

Use this class and call the required functions to create pdf

```
public class CreatePDF {

    private static Font normalFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 25,
            Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

    private static Font Head = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 35,
            Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);

    //Path is the path where you want your pdf to get stored
    public void createPDFDoc(ArrayList<notesWrapper> notesList,String path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));
            document.open();

            for(int i=0;i<notesList.size();i++)
            {               


                addContentHead(document,"Image "+(i+1));                
                addContent(document,notesList.get(i).message);
                if(i<notesList.size())
                {
                    document.newPage();
                }
            }

            document.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    private void addContent(Document document,String content) throws DocumentException {


        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();              
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

        if(!content.equalsIgnoreCase("insert note"))
        preface.add(new Paragraph(content, normalFont));

        else
            addEmptyLine(new Paragraph(), 1);

        addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
        document.add(preface);



    }


    private void addContentHead(Document document,String content) throws DocumentException {


        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();              
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

        preface.add(new Paragraph(content, Head));
        addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
        document.add(preface);



    }



    private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: By itext api do u mean the jar file? i already have the jar file and i have added to build path. I want to be able to come to this class through an activity class . please tell me how

Comment: please tell me how to come to this class from an activity class for eg.

Comment: Please go through this llink http://karanbalkar.com/2014/01/convert-text-file-to-pdf-document-in-java/ and if this helps, tell me :)

Comment: Ajeet here is my problem, i am able to execute itext operations in a java project. If i open an android project i have to remove the bootstrap entries in order to make it work but if i remove bootstrap entries i cannot run the android activity. if i have a class Public class PDF extends Activity{} i want to go from here to a class that does not extend activity how do i do it??